# How to add any number of digits to a string or remove digits from the string in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an SQL query which I give an input and receive an output. So I check whether the user is entering a variable or not. However I want to improve it.

Currently I use the following statement to check whether the input variable contains a variable or not, if they didn't enter an input the range is set automatically for them as seen below.

note:
-   `:StudentIdFrom` is an input field I configured to allow users to input for queries.
-     The `**:**` (colon means its an input)
-   `studentNo` is a character varying type of exactly 10 characters
- all inputs are strings.

```
(CASE
WHEN LENGTH(:StudentIdFrom ) > 0
THEN CAST(studentNo AS VARCHAR(10)) BETWEEN :StudentIdFrom AND 
(CASE 
WHEN LENGTH(:StudentIdUntil) > 0
THEN :StudentIdUntil
ELSE :StudentIdFrom 
END)
ELSE CAST(studentNo AS VARCHAR(10)) BETWEEN '0000000001' and '9999999999'
END
)
```

All I want to is that the user simply inputs a number without entering all the 0s in the statement.

Comment: Just left pad it with 0's where length < 10.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Some directly support `lpad()`, which is exactly what you want to do.

Comment: that is the worst formatted SQL I've seen in a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was in postgresql `LPAD(:studentIdFrom,10,'0')`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select replicate(0,10-len(field))+field
```

Comment: That answer didnt work specically for me however your answer did help direct me towards the correct answer! Thankyou for your help! 

The answer was in postgresql LPAD(:studentIdFrom,10,'0')